# What is a more specific word for "event" to denote things like wedding event, meeting event, etc?

Tags: word-choice

I see on the thesaurus dan "event" can means many things. Is there any alternative word that mean a group of people meeting for some kind of scheduled event, but does not carry meaning of tragedy, incident, or stuff that's happening?

Comment: It might depend on context, but I don't think native speakers would find **event** ambiguous, so you can use it in this way. In fact, an **event space** is the common term for "a place to rent for weddings/meetings/parties/etc." and an **event planner** is a person whose job is to arrange the logistics of such events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using the word *event* to describe a meeting of sorts.

If you are looking for alternatives, I would suggest: *congregation*, *gathering*, *assembly*.

Then again, some words have slightly different nuances, so really, it depends on what you want to get across to the reader.